# The specified type member '' is not supported in LINQ to Entities: I'm ordering by a property of the class I want to return

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.7 and Entity Framework Code First 6.1.3.

I'm trying to do a select from table `Aggregation` and return an Array of `AggregationData` instances.

```
DbSet<Aggregation> dbSet = dbContext.Set<Aggregation>();

public class Aggregation
{
    public int AggregationId { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public bool SentToNextLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AggregationChildren> AggregationChildren { get; set; }

    public virtual Code Code { get; set; }

    public Aggregation()
    {
        SentToNextLevel = false; // Default value
    }
}

public class AggregationData
{
    public int AggregationId { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public List<AggregationChildrenData> Children { get; set; }
}

AggregationData[] aggregations = null;

do
{
    aggregations = dbSet
        .Select(a =>
            new AggregationData()
            {
                Parent = a.Code.Serial,
                Children = a.AggregationChildren
                    .Select(agCh => new { agCh.Code.Serial, agCh.Position })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(agCh => new AggregationChildrenData() { Serial = agCh.Serial, Position = agCh.Position })
                    .ToList()
            })
        .OrderBy(a => a.AggregationId)
        .Skip(() => skip)
        .Take(() => take)
        .ToArray();

    foreach (AggregationData agg in aggregations)
    {
        sw.Write(AggregationToJSON(agg, isFirstAgg));
        if (isFirstAgg)
            isFirstAgg = false;
    }

    skip += take;
}
while ((aggregations != null) && (aggregations.Length == take));
```

The problem is with this statement: `.OrderBy(a => a.AggregationId)`. This `AggregationId` is from `AggregationData` class, not from `Aggregation`.

I get the following error when I execute that statement:

> The specified type member 'AggregationId' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, feature members, and feature navigation
>   properties are supported.

I need it ordered by `Aggregation.AggregationId`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
.Select(a =>
            new AggregationData()
            {
                Parent = a.Code.Serial,
                Children = a.AggregationChildren
                    .Select(agCh => new { agCh.Code.Serial, agCh.Position })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(agCh => new AggregationChildrenData() { Serial = agCh.Serial, Position = agCh.Position })
                    .ToList()
            })
```

You need to set AggragateId =>

```
.Select(a =>
            new AggregationData()
            {
                Parent = a.Code.Serial,
                Children = a.AggregationChildren
                    .Select(agCh => new { agCh.Code.Serial, agCh.Position })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(agCh => new AggregationChildrenData() { Serial = agCh.Serial, Position = agCh.Position })
                    .ToList()
                AggregationId = a.AggregationId
            })
```

And then you can `OrderBy`. `OrderBy` will be ever a enumerable of `AggregationData` so you can't `OrderBy` on `Aggregation.AggregationId` from this `Select`.